# conditional Probability of a Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

These days, I want to calculate the probability below:
$$P\left(x_6-x_5\le\mathop{\mathop{max}\limits_{1\le i,j\le4}}\limits_{i\neq j}(|x_i-x_j|)\right)$$ 
$$x_i\mathop{\sim}^{iid}N(0,\sigma^2),i=1\sim 6$$
I obtain $P=0.89$ by software simulation and the probability is irrelevant with the $\sigma^2$. So how to calculate the probability?

Comment: Not sure if there is any "closed-form" solution for this. Note that the RHS is the sample range of $4$ i.i.d. normals, and the LHS is just a normal random variable with double variance, independent of the RHS. You can always divide $\sigma$ in both side and thus the problem is independent of $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also doubt if there is any  "closed-form" solution for this question.